# Where can I find SpringLayout in IntelliJ's GUI Builder?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

How do I get [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html) to work in IntelliJ's GUI builder?  It does not show up as a layout option.